# projecting multiple images onto an object

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am new to this field of blender (use of modifier UV project).

Let me expose my question.

I use visual SFM with a collection of picture to get cameras position, orientation and focal length (blender camera tracker fails if focal length is varying across the photoset).

I then use OPENMVS to get a reconstructed mesh. Under meshlab, the results look great.

I need to go further and rework these result (remove shadow cast,..) Whereas the mesh is a good guideline for my needs (block model houses or places), I am not satisfied with the UV map it provides (It looks like a mosaic of small pictures than the result of thoughtful unwrapping) and I can't work with this UVmap.

Up to now, I usually imported camera and mesh, reworked the mesh to simplify to primitives (flat faces, cylinders,..) , unwrapped the mesh (unwrap properly, unwrap projected from view for different images) and made my best to get a decent UVmap (use stenciling with corresponding picture). For example, you can watch this tutorial (blender 2.79 texture a face on youtube):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1rhn_ma9Wo

When I read the the answer to the following question, I thought that the tool would provide a basis to improve my workflow :
[Projecting multiple images onto an object with UV Project modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76774/projecting-multiple-images-onto-an-object-with-uv-project-modifiers)

But I don't understand how, starting from a mesh, multiple cameras and the corresponding collection of pictures, I can produce the required object (projection map) and set the parameters in the plugin.

Can anyone explain me the workflow ?

Phil

edit 1 : post edited to make my question clearer (or so I hope).

edit 2 : browsing the Q/A, I found a post with a similar question
[Projection painting from images sequences/movies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66798/projection-painting-from-images-sequences-movies?rq=1)